# How to send an array of characters from Html webpage input to esp32 using form, webpage hosted on esp32?

Tags: forms, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I want to send array of type time characters from html webpage to esp32 using forms, webpage hosted on esp32.
Below is my code.
Form is being generated as array but esp32 is unable to read the whole array, instead its just reading one time element.
I am using ESPAsyncwebserver library on arduino ide.
(I am a beginner, i cannot code esp with anything but arduino ide and this is my first que.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dynamic Time Inputs</title>
<style>
    /* Style the body element */
    body {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    /* Style the h1 element */
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    /* Style the form and its elements */
    form {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    input[type="number"] {
      width: 200px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    input[type="time"] {
      width: 200px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    button[type="submit"] {
      width: 150px;
      height: 40px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      font-size: 18px;
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .time-input {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .time-input label {
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    /* Style the background */
    .background {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #99c2ff 0%, #aaaaaa 100%);
      z-index: -1;
    }
</style>
<script>
  // function to generate dynamic time inputs
  function generateTimeInputs() {
    // get the number of time inputs from the user
    var numTimes = parseInt(document.getElementById("numTimes").value);

    // get the time inputs div
    var timeInputsDiv = document.getElementById("timeInputs");

    // clear any existing time inputs
    timeInputsDiv.innerHTML = "";

    // create new time input text boxes
    for (var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
      var newTimeInput = document.createElement("input");
      newTimeInput.type = "time";
      newTimeInput.name = "time[]";
      timeInputsDiv.appendChild(newTimeInput);
     
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="background"></div>
    <h1>Dynamic Time Inputs</h1>
    <form action="/get">
  <label for="numTimes">Number of Time Inputs:</label>
  <input type="number" id="numTimes" name="numTimes" min="1" max="10">
  <button type="button" onclick="generateTimeInputs()">Generate Time Inputs</button>

  <div id="timeInputs"></div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my arduino code for reading the form:

```
char TIME[] = "time[]", NUM[]="numTimes";
String tym,nm;
/* OTHER CODE*/
 server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {

     nm = request->getParam(NUM)->value();
    tym = request->getParam(TIME)->value();
    Serial.println(tym);
    Serial.println(nm);
   
    request->send(200, "text/html", "HTTP GET request sent to your ESP on input field.");
  });
```